# PL/pgSQL query - loop through table issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, concatenation, plpgsql

I have written the following function in PL/pgSQL, which is supposed to loop through a table and collect values stored in the `points` column for each existing row. Now, my issue is that I'm not quite sure if it is possible to concatenate all of these field values into a single `character varying` datatype object.

Currently my function contains the following code (however it is still not working as expected):

```
DECLARE 
     _r record;
     point character varying;
     test character varying;

BEGIN

FOR _r IN EXECUTE ' SELECT st_y(a.'|| quote_ident(column_name) || ') AS p1, st_x(a.'||  quote_ident(column_name) || ') AS p2
       FROM ' || quote_ident (table_name) ||' AS a'
LOOP
       test = _r;
       point = point || '|' || test;
END LOOP;

RETURN point;
END;
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this in the simplest way?

Comment: You forgot the function header, please include it. I really don't know why some people remove the header. It's an integral part of the function. Also provide sample values and an example what your result should look  like. And declare your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use the built-in `string_agg()` function. If it is only that then a SQL function is enough.

```
create or replace function r()
returns text as $$

    select string_agg(s.*::text, ','::text)
    from (
        values (1, 2), (3, 4)
    ) s(a, b)
    ;
$$ language sql

select r();
      r      
-------------
 (1,2),(3,4)
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on what I have to change in my function please. @Clodoaldo

Comment: @IT_info: Care to update your question with the requested clarifications first?

Answer (score 0):

Also, wouldn't this `point = point || '|' || test;` constantly overwrite `point`?

Should it be `point := point || '|' || test;`?

Also, `_r` is declared as record, so test would have to be set `_r.a`, since that is what you named the result.